# I am able to use PUT to act like GET when using my REST API

Tags: python, rest, go

I wrote a simple REST API (just learning) using `Go` and I am calling it using `python requests`. I have two methods, "update_x", which updates the value of the resource, "get_x_times_n" which gets the value of the resource. Logically, I would think that I need (and can only use) `put` for "update_x" and `get` for "get_x_times_n". However, I can very easily implement a method, such that I can call "get_x_times_n" using `put`.

Here is my `Go` code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    my_resource := MyResource{x: 0}

    http.HandleFunc("/update_x", my_resource.update_x)
    http.HandleFunc("/get_x_times_n", my_resource.get_x_times_n)
    http.HandleFunc("/get_x_times_n_wierd", my_resource.get_x_times_n_wierd)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil)
}

type MyResource struct {
    x int 
}

func (mr *MyResource) update_x(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.Reader(r.Body))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := r.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var delta int 

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &delta)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    mr.x += delta 
}

func (mr *MyResource) get_x_times_n(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(r.Form)

    n_str := r.Form["n"][0]

    n, err := strconv.Atoi(n_str)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result := mr.x * n 

    fmt.Fprint(w, result)
}


func (mr *MyResource) get_x_times_n_wierd(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.Body)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.Reader(r.Body))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := r.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var n int 

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &n)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result := mr.x * n 

    fmt.Fprint(w, result)
}
```

And here is my Python session:

```
In [51]: import requests

In [52]: r = requests.put("http://localhost:8000/update_x", data='5')
In [53]: r = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/get_x_times_n", params={"n": 5})

In [54]: r.content
Out[54]: '25'

In [55]: r = requests.put("http://localhost:8000/get_x_times_n_wierd", data="5")

In [56]: r.content
Out[56]: '25'
```

I can see why this is happening, since in both methods I have `r *http.Request`, I can pass whatever data I want. And also in both methods I have access to `w http.ResponseWriter`, I can write anything I want.

My question is: What am I doing wrong? Am I just abusing `requests` when using the API? Did I set up my API completely wrong? (If the API was set up properly something like this would not be allowed?). Or both? Or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing builtin into the server will figure out that a request should have been a PUT request. (How could it?) It's up to you to handle that. The default behavior for the go http server is simply to ignore the method. (Some other systems have other default, such as only supporting GET by default). If you want a particular request to only work when used with a particular http method, you have to enforce it. Something like:

```
if r.Method != "PUT" {
   sendRejection(w);
}
```

My recommendation is to always enforce that the correct method is being used.